# Text ease up on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a simple 1 page website, which when you click the menu link it scrolls to the desired section. - Currently, I have it so the content for that specific section fades in very slowly, but I want to change the effect, so once the page scrolls down the content slides up from the bottom, rather than fade in.

Here is the javascript code for the fade in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.fade-in').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
        bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 800; 

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},10000);

        }

    }); 

  });

});
```

CSS:

```
.fade-in { opacity: 0; }
```

Is there a way to simply manipulate this code, so it alters the content to slide up rather than fade in?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

### SIMPLE FIX (not ideal but works fine)

Changed:

```
$(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},10000);
```

To:

```
$(this).animate({'margin-top':'0'},10000);
```

And CSS to:

```
.fade-in { margin-top: 1000px; }
```

Comment: You may try to use that ( wow.js) , http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: Just change the `animate` call... duh?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. What may seem straight forward to one, is not always the case for another... is it a case of changing the CSS within the animate to ease-in?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jQuery, you can use `slideToggle()` as described in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

```
$(this).slideToggle()
```

Comment: This seems to make the page go crazy, with the div moving up, and back down constantly.